# How to redirect to the top of a .csv file using SetFilePointer

Tags: c++, csv

Basically, I'm creating an error log for a series of test to be ran that records failures and successes. The error log is a **.csv** file. Basically, the program is taking a list of tests and they are named #testlist.txt for example. Within each #testlist.txt is a series of tests.

For example,

#testlist.txt contains:

Test1.txt

Test2.txt

Test3.txt

Within Test1.txt, there are 3 subtests. These subtests can fail or succeed; hence, the success and failure rate. So what this error log reports is the statistics for each Test, and also a global success and failure rate for all the tests with the #testlist.

My assignment is to have the statistics of the #testlist at the top of the list instead of at the bottom. **The problem is:** I don't know how to redirect to the top of the file after all the individual test statistics have been printed to print the global statistics to the .csv file.

I am using *C++* in *Visual Basic 2008*. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful! Thank you so much!

## Update:

So this may seem like a dumb question, but I went to MSDN to look up SetFilePointer which is what my colleague suggested I try, but it wasn't making sense as to why it wasn't working in my code.

```
if (SetFilePointer(m_pDlg->sumLog,0,NULL,FILE_BEGIN) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER){
        fprintf(m_pDlg->sumLog, "\n\n%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%0.2f%%,%0.2f%%", pDlg->testlistFileName, s, m_pDlg->m_uiValTotal, 
            m_pDlg->m_uiValPassed, m_pDlg->m_uiValFailedGlobal,
            m_pDlg->getSuccessRate(m_pDlg->m_uiValTotal, m_pDlg->m_uiValPassed),
            m_pDlg->getFailureRate(m_pDlg->m_uiValTotal, m_pDlg->m_uiValFailedGlobal));
    }
```

Perhaps I'm understanding this method wrong and if anyone could shed some light on this and help me to get this working, that'd be greatly appreciated!

**The problem:** SetFilePointer is always equal to INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER.

Some more information:

```
m_pDlg->sumLog
```

This is the name of the file I'm writing to. At the end of this file (maybe about 1GB of data), I'm trying to get to the beginning to insert this line.
I've declared it as

```
FILE* sumLog;
```

If more information is needed, I will be happy to provide.

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: C++ in Visual Basic 2008? What does that mean?

Comment: Spit the output into error-logs and statistics and merge these files finally.

Comment: It's some kind of elvish... @JonathanWood

Comment: Please look up the following: `rewind()`, `ostream::seekp`, `ostream::tellp`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Hi Thomas! Thanks for your suggestion! I tried all those functions and for some reason, it only prints it after everything. I tried rewind(m_pDlg->sumLog) and it prints the next thing at the end.
Then, fseek(m_pDlg->sumLog, 0, SEEK_SET) and still the same affect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to write new data at the top of the file after the file already has content?

If so, the answer is that trying to insert data anywhere but the end of the file is horribly inefficient. Basically, you'd need to shift every byte after the insertion point to a lower position in the file. This involves reading and rewriting each byte in a very complex way.

So the best solution is to write your new content to a new file, and then copy the original file to the new file, after your new content. That is much more efficient and easier to implement.

Comment: This is a great suggestion! Thank you!
However, I was wondering what would happen if I left a space at the top of the file for it to be overwritten?

Comment: Yes, that approach would work. It's just that A) You need to make sure you leave enough spaces, and B) To do that, you'll probably have too many so that your data has a bunch of spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply insert such variable length data to the start of an already opened file. You'll need a different approach:

1. You read in the `.csv` skipping the statistics line, and move it to a backup file.
2. You calculate the new statistics based on what was read in in step 1.
3. You reopen the `.csv` file as output print the header and statistics first, and afterwards print all of the other data lines that were used to calculate the statistics